# Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

If I execute the Selenium Manager from CMD (same app folder) it shows everything fine:

```
windows> ./selenium-manager --browser chrome
[2024-02-28T22:36:35.504Z INFO ] Driver path: C:\Temp\Selenium\chromedriver.exe
[2024-02-28T22:36:35.504Z INFO ] Browser path: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

But if I run my application in the Visual Studio, I get this error:

```
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

> OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchDriverException: 'Unable to obtain chrome using
> Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit:
> [https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location'](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location%27)
>
> WebDriverException: Selenium Manager process exited abnormally with 69
> code: D:\App\bin\Debug\net8.0\selenium-manager\windows\selenium-manager.exe
> --browser "chrome" --language-binding csharp --output json Standard Output >> {   "logs": [
> {
> "level": "ERROR",
> "timestamp": 1709160132,
> "message": "Driver unavailable: Driver path: "
> }   ],   "result": {
> "code": 69,
> "message": "Driver unavailable: Driver path: ",
> "driver_path": "",
> "browser_path": ""   } }

There's a lot of topics related to the same issue but without solutioun. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using the most up-to-date version of Selenium? Chromedriver changed where to get the exes a while ago and that broke any versions prior to the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uninstalling and installing Chrome WebBrowser I deleted the chromedriver.exe in my project folder and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager w/o any extra needs of driver download. It will download any needed driver and set all from scratch.

Comment: That's essentially what Selenium Manager is now except it's built into Selenium.

Comment: Yes and the idea was not using any downloaded files. So the author solved the issue via just removing the .exe. Using different library was a suggestion as I find it more simple. @JeffC